# Well/Navbar in bootstrap not behaving responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

How to make my page responsive,By responsive I mean It should look the 
same in desktop and laptop the same.But I get two rows of well(Bootstrap class) in laptop and 3 rows in desktop.I would want it to have 3 rows.I have a design which is in pixels,should I need to implement height and width in percentage to make it look the same.I have the same css for laptop and desktop how can this be achieved.
I have a navbar should I need to place it in a container to make it responsive?
Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse container-fluid ">

            <img src="assets/img/Logo.png" class="santanderIcon" > 
            <div class="hline" > </div>
            <p class="e2e-label">E2E Portal</p>
            <p class="login-label">Login</p>
            <p class="help-label">Help</p> 

        </nav>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row " style="margin-top: 100px">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="assets/img/Ideas.png">
                    <h3>Ideas</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit  adipisicing elit...</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, exercitation  laboris...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="assets/img/Business Case.png">
                    <h3>Business Case</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  elit...</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, exercitation  laboris...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="assets/img/Project Cost Calculator.png">
                    <h3>Project Cost Calculator</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  elit...</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam,  laboris...</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="assets/img/Dashboard.png">
                    <h3>Dashboard</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit...</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam,exercitation laboris...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="assets/img/Manage My Project.png">
                    <h3>Manage my projects</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  elit...</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis  ullamco laboris...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="assets/img/Personalization.png">
                    <h3>Personalization</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  elit...</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam,  ullamco laboris...</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="assets/img/My BAAR.png">
                    <h3>My BAAR</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  elit...</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis  ullamco laboris...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="assets/img/My Approval.png">
                    <h3>My Approvals</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  elit...</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam,  ullamco laboris...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="assets/img/My Approval.png">
                    <h3>User Management</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  elit...</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam,  ullamco laboris...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


/* Bootstrap classes */

html, body { height: 100%; } 

body{
  background-color: #EDEEF2;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
}

.navbar{
  min-height: 80px;

}

.santander-label{
  display: inline-block;
   color:white;
   font-size:30pt;
   vertical-align: middle;

}

.login-label{
  display: inline-block;
  color:white;
  padding-left:550px;
  font-size:20pt;
  vertical-align: middle;

 }

 .e2e-label{
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
    padding-left:100px;
    font-size:30pt;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }

  .help-label{
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
    padding-left:50px;
    font-size:20pt;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }


/*Overide default class of bootstrap */
.navbar-inverse{
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#EC0000,#740808);
  border-bottom:none;
}


.well{  
  background-color:white !important;
  border-style:none !important;
  border: none ;
  border-radius:unset;
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px lightgrey;
}

.santanderIcon{
  height:30px;
  width:160px;
  padding-left:1.5625%;
  padding-right:2.0312%;
}

.hline{
  display:inline-block;
  height:28px; 
  width:2px;
  background-color: white;
  position:relative;
  left:30px;
  top:10px;
 }
```

Comment: bootstrap provides col-lg-* for desktop/large screen which you can use. And if you want to limit the width of your website to make it look same in desktop and laptop use can use class container which will have highest width as 1170px. Also if you can provide some sample code I can help better

Comment: Added the code please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to put your nav content inside a container.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse container-fluid ">
        <div class="container">

            <img src="assets/img/Logo.png" class="santanderIcon" > 
            <div class="hline" > </div>
            <p class="e2e-label">E2E Portal</p>
            <p class="login-label">Login</p>
            <p class="help-label">Help</p> 
        </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Bootstrap Grid System.

[image]

A Laptop is a medium device (moslty). To set the gutter to 3 on a medium device you have to add the .col-md class to every div.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
```

Besides that check your navbar code. It looks very wrong.